# Changing biblatex reference printing style to make it similar to amsrefs

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, amsrefs

Third question in my series of questions on TeX.SE for an annotated bibliography ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499458/annotated-bibliography-two-bibliographies-one-bib-file), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500428/annotated-bibliography-two-bibliographies-labels-are-not-printed-correctly)). This one has the same MWE but another issue. 
At the moment, the reference formatting for

```
@article{ref5,
        author={Hardy, G. H. and Littlewood, J. E. },
        title={{Contributions to the theory of the Riemann zeta-function and the theory of the distribution of primes}},
        year={1916},
        journal={Acta Math.},
        volume={41},
        number={1},
        annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref1, ref4, ref3}.},
    }
```

looks like:

[image]

But I want it to look like

[image]

This second image belongs to the old format of our project in which we used `amsrefs` and classic `bibtex`. The good thing about `amsrefs` is that it has a beautiful structure for each bib entry type (article/book/compilation/thesis) such as bold/italic titles and supports the field MRnumber. But we changed to the modern `biblatex` and a separate bib file and now we are looking for a method to mock as many `amsrefs` styles as possible with the least manual effort.

Specifically, we want the following changes in style:

- Add MRnumber from the MRnumber field in entries
- Remove the word "In:" before each journal title
- Instead of "VOLUME.NUMBER (YEAR)", have "VOLUME (YEAR), no. NUMBER"
- Remove "pp. "
- Omit the ISSN

(I could not make a full MWE because it would be too long if I want to include all types of reference we have in the bibliography. [Here](http://parvardi.com/wp-content/uploads/evolving.pdf) is the old version of the project with `amsrefs` which has the ideal formatting for us. Take a look to see different types of bib entries such as book, article, or thesis.)

There is also another issue that is more complicated: a few of the papers in our collection have something like `1961/62` (rather than `1961` or `1962`) in their `year` field in the bib file. Thus, when ordered chronologically, the bibliography puts such entries before all other entries. One solution might be to change `1961/62` to `1961` but we aim to be loyal to the references to avoid later confusion for the readers. Here is my MWE and screenshot to reflect this issue:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[sorting=ynt, backend=biber, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {ref1,
    AUTHOR = {Chebyshev, P.},
    TITLE = {{Lettre de M. le professeur Tchebychev a M. Fuss, sur un nouveau th{e}oreme relatif aux nombres premiers contenus dans la formes $4n+1$ et $4n+3$.}},
    FJOURNAL = {Bull. de la Classe phys. math. de l'Acad. Imp. des Sciences St. Petersburg},
    VOLUME = {11},
    YEAR = {1853},
    LANGUAGE = {french},
    annotation = {Chebyshev's paper which was the starting point of the subject.},
}
@article{ref2,
    AUTHOR = {Phragmen, P.},
    TITLE = {{Sur le logarithme integral et la fonction $f(x)$ de Riemann}},
    YEAR  = {1891},
    FJOURNAL = {\"{O}fversigt af Kongl. Vetenskaps--Akademiens F\"{o}handlingar.},
    LANGUAGE = {French},
    VOLUME = {48},
    annotation = {\blindtext \par This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.},
}
@article{ref3,
    AUTHOR = {Landau, E.},
    TITLE = {{U}ber einen {S}atz von {T}schebyschef},
    JOURNAL = {Math. Ann.},
    FJOURNAL = {Mathematische Annalen},
    VOLUME = {61},
    YEAR = {1906},
    NUMBER = {4},
}
@article{ref4,
    author={Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Sur la distribution des nombres premiers}},
    year={1961/62},
    volume={158},
    journal={Comptes Rendus de l'Acad. Sci. Paris},
    language={French},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.}
}
@article{ref5,
    author={Hardy, G. H. and Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Contributions to the theory of the Riemann zeta-function and the theory of the distribution of primes}},
    year={1916},
    journal={Acta Math.},
    volume={41},
    number={1},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref1, ref4, ref3}.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}



\section{Chronological bibliography}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image]
PS. In the end, if we can cover all the criteria, it might even be possible to publish this as an update to the AMS formatting and maybe their referencing system in [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/index.html).

Comment: Please note that questions about recreating entire styles are usually not a great fit for this site. It can be quite some work to do that. It would be better if you could split up the required changes into separate sub-questions about one specific issue. Then people can answer the requests separately and other people with a similar problem can benefit from the questions.

Comment: @moewe I think those I mentioned specifically are most important. I might be able to do similar editions for other reference types once I see a few examples.

Comment: For the MR number thingy have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306908/35864

Comment: For the "in:" see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864

Comment: For the "pp." you can find something in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416043/35864

Comment: The ISSN can be disabled with the `isbn` switch (which controls both the ISSN and the ISBN): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23117/35864. If you want independent control over ISBN and ISSN have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40097/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440251/35864

Answer (score 4):

Please ask only about one specific issue per question. Since most of the things you mention are addressed elsewhere

- The `MRnumber` is covered in [Switching from amsrefs to biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306908/35864).
- The "in:" in [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864).
- The "pp." in [Remove 'In' and 'pp' from bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416043/35864) and [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864).
- The ISSN in [Biblatex: Get rid of ISSN, URLs and DOIs in references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23117/35864) or [Disable ISSN but keep ISBN with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40097/35864) and [biblatex: Only show doi or ISSN or ISBN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440251/35864).

I will focus on the desired format

> VOLUME (YEAR), no. NUMBER

To get this format we need to redefine the macro `journal+issuetitle`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit}
```

Compare this to [the original definition of `journal+issuetitle` and `volume+number+eid` in `standard.bbx`, ll. 748-768](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx#L748-L768).

In full with a few more tweaks

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mrnumber.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{mrnumber}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{mrnumber}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=ynt, datamodel=mrnumber,
  isbn=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{mrnumber}{%
  MR\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{mrnumber}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {ref1,
    AUTHOR = {Chebyshev, P.},
    TITLE = {{Lettre de M. le professeur Tchebychev a M. Fuss, sur un nouveau th{e}oreme relatif aux nombres premiers contenus dans la formes $4n+1$ et $4n+3$.}},
    FJOURNAL = {Bull. de la Classe phys. math. de l'Acad. Imp. des Sciences St. Petersburg},
    VOLUME = {11},
    YEAR = {1853},
    LANGUAGE = {french},
    annotation = {Chebyshev's paper which was the starting point of the subject.},
}
@article{ref2,
    AUTHOR = {Phragmen, P.},
    TITLE = {{Sur le logarithme integral et la fonction $f(x)$ de Riemann}},
    YEAR  = {1891},
    FJOURNAL = {\"{O}fversigt af Kongl. Vetenskaps--Akademiens F\"{o}handlingar.},
    LANGUAGE = {French},
    VOLUME = {48},
    annotation = {\blindtext \par This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.},
}
@article{ref3,
    AUTHOR = {Landau, E.},
    TITLE = {{U}ber einen {S}atz von {T}schebyschef},
    JOURNAL = {Math. Ann.},
    FJOURNAL = {Mathematische Annalen},
    VOLUME = {61},
    YEAR = {1906},
    NUMBER = {4},
}
@article{ref4,
    author={Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Sur la distribution des nombres premiers}},
    year={1961/62},
    volume={158},
    journal={Comptes Rendus de l'Acad. Sci. Paris},
    language={French},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.}
}
@article{ref5,
    author={Hardy, G. H. and Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Contributions to the theory of the Riemann zeta-function and the theory of the distribution of primes}},
    year={1916},
    journal={Acta Math.},
    volume={41},
    number={1},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref1, ref4, ref3}.},
}
@article{grabiner,
  author    = {David J. Grabiner},
  title     = {Brownian motion in a Weyl chamber, non-colliding particles, and random matrices},
  journal   = {Annales de l'Institut Henri Poincare (B) Probability and Statistics},
  volume    = {35},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {177-204},
  year      = {1999},
  doi       = {10.1016/S0246-0203(99)80010-7},
  mrnumber  = {1678525},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, title=Chronological bibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: More AMS-like bibliography.]

Comment: This is perfect @moewe except in your screenshot, the first reference has `1961/62` in its year field and that mixes up the chronological sorting. We have several such entries in our annotated bibliography and those are the only annoying ones!

Comment: @AmirHossein Yes, that is a different issue. Please ask a new question about that.

Comment: Sure, going to do that right away.

Comment: Here it is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500755